# How to share connection pool among multiple Java applications

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I'm implementing several JavaSE applications on single server. Is it possible to setup a single connection pool (e.g. C3P0) and share among these applications? I just want to have an easy way to manage the total number of DB connections.

Is there any drawbacks using such centralized connection pool?

Thank you,
Wilson

Comment: What sort of applications? Swing? RMI? And what do you mean by "server"? A physical machine, or an application server?

Comment: I doubt that there is anyway for separate JVM instances/processes to share a physical resource such as a database connection.

Comment: Simple JavaSE applications and one physical linux machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the same data source defined in the server for all application to share the same DB connection pool easily.

One obvious drawback would be that performance of independent application may degrade due to a load on totally unrelated application which would be hard to figure out.

Comment: Also, if one application uses all the connections in the pool, the other ones will stop working.